# Validation error while using multi-input tools in ReAct Agent - relating to number of inputs

Tags: python, langchain

I am using a function to get financial information for a company and yr and coupling it with a react agent. The Action Input is generating the correct input: `{"co": "Tesla", "fundamental": "sales", "yr": "FY22"}` but the agent still gives the Validation error for inputs `"fundamental"` and `"yr"`.

When I run `get_financial_info.invoke({"co":"Tesla"})` it gives the same error which means the other 2 arguments are not getting passed correctly.

Looks like an output parser issue. Can someone please help? Am a newbie to Langchain Agents.

**System Info**

- Model is GPT-4

Google Colab

`%pip install openai langchain pypdf faiss-gpu tiktoken`

```py
@tool
def get_financial_info(co: str, fundamental: str, yr: str) -> float:
    """useful for getting information on a fundamental for a given company and year"""
 <code for returning relevant financial information>

#get_financial_info.invoke({"co":"Tesla", "fundamental":"sales", "yr":"FY22"}) - WORKS OK

tools = [get_financial_info]

template = """Answer the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:\
{tools}\

Use the following format:\

Question: the input question you must answer\
Thought: you should always think about what to do\
Action: the action to take, should be one of [{tool_names}]\
Action Input: the input to the action\
If there's an error, re run the tool with corrected input\
Observation: the result of the action\
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)\
Thought: I now know the final answer\
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question\

Begin!\

Question: {input}\
Thought:{agent_scratchpad}
"""
prompt_template = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)

react_agent = create_react_agent(llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt_template)
# executes the logical steps we created
react_agent_executor = AgentExecutor(
    agent=react_agent, tools=tools, verbose=True, handle_parsing_errors=True
)

query = "What is the sales for Tesla in FY22?"
react_agent_executor.invoke({"input": query})
```

Output:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
I need to use the get_financial_info tool to get the sales information for Tesla in FY22.
Action: get_financial_info
Action Input: {"co": "Tesla", "fundamental": "sales", "yr": "FY22"}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-38d1c873087b> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 query = "What is the sales for Tesla in FY22?"
----> 2 react_agent_executor.invoke({"input": query})

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py in __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data)
    339         values, fields_set, validation_error = validate_model(__pydantic_self__.__class__, data)
    340         if validation_error:
--> 341             raise validation_error
    342         try:
    343             object_setattr(__pydantic_self__, '__dict__', values)

ValidationError: 2 validation errors for get_financial_infoSchema
fundamental
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
yr
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Answer (score 0):

The agent created by the `create_react_agent` does not support tools with multiple parameters. To solve your problem, we can try the following options:

- Replace the ReAct agent with the [Structured Chat](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/structured_chat)
- Use a single input that is actually a dictionary with all your parameters.

Check this [GitHub discusssion](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/18083) or [this issue](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/4197) (outdated) for more information.